# Can anyone teach me this JS code given below?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, numbers, alert

How it alerts 'Correct' if the array and defined array variables are different?
'number' is only defined, not 'numbers'.

```js
let number = [];
numbers=[1,2,1,0];
if(number[0]==number[2]){
 alert('correct');
}
```

Comment: Becuse number[0] and number[2] returns undefined and in JS `undefined == undefined` is true.

Comment: You are not referencing `numbers` anywhere in your code. The behavior of the code doesn't change if you remove the `numbers=....` line.

Comment: @palaѕн I was in a huge doubt that how can this be true, But I saw it in a tutorial video and I knew that it is going to end up being an error, But the tutor also didn't knew this! Weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compute the result of `number[0]` and `number[2]` separately, you will see that `number[0]` is `undefined` and `number[2]` is `undefined`.

In JavaScript `undefined == undefined` is `true` and so the alert is shown.

Comment: I got it, Thanks! I was mad because it is done in a tutorial video, and unfortunately the tutor herself didn't knew that it is a typo!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the rest of your learning and welcome to the community!

Answer (score 0):

`number` is an empty array. Thus, at any index, the value will be `undefined`.

`number[0]` === `undefined`
`number[2]` === `undefined`

Thus, `number[0] === number[2]`